# How to interpolate between InterpolatingFunction objects

Tags: finite-element-method, interpolation

For some reasons I need to implement the method of lines instead of using the NDSolve function directly. As described in this [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), this is how the simplest PDE can be solved:

```
H = 1.0; n = 10; dx = H/n;

U[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];

eqns = Thread[
   D[U[t], t] == 
    Join[{D[Sin[2 π t], t] + (Sin[2 π t] - Subscript[u, 0][t])}, 
     ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/dx^2, U[t], {1, 2}, {Subscript[u, n - 1][t]}]/8]];

initc = Thread[U[0] == Table[0, {n + 1}]];

lines = NDSolveValue[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, 4}];

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{i dx, t, lines[[i + 1]]}, {i, 0, n}]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}]
```

A a result, functions $u_i(t)$  (i.e. "lines") in certain "space" points are obtained. NDSolve gives these functions as [InterpolatingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) objects. The solution in between lines can be found by interpolation.

How to get a two-dimensional InterpolatingFunction object from the functions $u_i(t)$, similarly to what NDSolve gives if I solve the equation directly?

I can create an array of point from the InterpolatingFunction and then interpolate, as follows

```
array = 
  Table[{{i dx, t1}, lines[[i + 1]] /. t -> t1}, {i, 0, n}, {t1, 0, 4, 0.1}];

function = ListInterpolation[array];

Plot3D[function[x, t], {t, 0, 4}, {x, 0, H}, PlotRange -> All]
```

but is there a better options? Can I somehow use the InterpolatingFunction object directly without introducing this additional division into points? Is there a build-in function to do this? I think my solution is not very effective  because at first NDSolve interpolates between calculation points (when giving ODEs solutions), that I take this interpolation, and divide it into points again, and then, again, I interpolate...

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial section [Transient PDEs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). There you'll find a slightly different (but efficient) approach that may suite your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the FEM method suggested by @user21 does not work, here is one way to interpolate between the line solutions.  Since you've got `lines` in terms of the global variable `t`, we have to take some care with it (e.g., the use of `Block[{t = t0}...` in `sol2d`).  It does an order-3 interpolation between the values of the four `lines` solutions whose x-coordinates are nearest the argument `x`.

```
xx = Range[0, n] dx;
xnf = Nearest[xx -> Automatic];

sol2d[x_?NumericQ, t0_?NumericQ] := Block[{t = t0},
  InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{xx[[#]], lines[[#]]} &@xnf[x, 4]], x]]

Plot3D[sol2d[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> {xx}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's about 3 times slower than the OP's `ListInterpolation`, but it uses the values from `lines` at time `t` instead of re-interpolating.  This is slightly faster (~5%), since it avoids evaluating all the `lines` at `t0`:

```
sol2d[x_?NumericQ, t0_?NumericQ] := Block[{t},
  With[{xi = xnf[x, 4]},
   With[{yy = lines[[xi]]},
    t = t0;
    InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{xx[[xi]], yy}], x]
    ]]]
```